# Creating dll in C from source and heading files

Tags: c, dll

How can I create dll from separate source and heading files (written in C).
I have

```
extrfunc.h
tricclib.c
tricclib.def
tricclibql.c
```

And I need to create dll (using c not c++) from these components.
These files are just here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EyvxHxiOLJqNp7sZwn0YOsOT2eRJLCL1?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what compiler you're using. Because you are calling it a DLL, I am assuming you are running Windows. When I compile on Windows I use the MinGW port of GCC. Assuming this, do the following:

1. Make sure you have the correct `__declspec` on your functions.
2. Compile each source file to an object file with commands like: `gcc -c -o example.o example.c`
3. Link it with something like `gcc -shared -o output_dll.dll object1.o object2.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a`